# What is a dry electron?

Tags: water, photochemistry

I was reading about water photolysis which produces a positive water radical and a dry electron, or an excited water $\ce{H2O^*}$ through the following equation

$$\ce{
H2O ->[$hv$] H2O^{.+} + e_{dry}^-, or~ H2O^*
}$$
(as seen in [this link](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/cr0682047?journalCode=chreay))

By opposition I have also seen $\ce{e_{aq}^-}$ (as seen in pp. 2 of this [link](https://www3.nd.edu/~ndrlrcdc/Compilations/rxn.pdf)).

I can understand the "positive water" and even the "excited water", but what is a "dry electron"? And what is an $\ce{e_{aq}^-}$ (wet electron? I am unsure of how to translate the term I had learned to english). Why not simply say "free electron"?

Comment: There are a zillion hits on a google search. It is evidently an electron that retains some of the kinetic energy from whatever interaction created the free electron. https://books.google.com/books?id=W_d6qz2YMzMC&pg=PA157&lpg=PA157&dq=%22dry+electron%22&source=bl&ots=3ViHtmy7Oc&sig=kHnAw9yVJONSovdjPsBDdvI6P4s&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjazort6uDJAhVM_mMKHS-wCh44ChDoAQgrMAQ#v=onepage&q=%22dry%20electron%22&f=false

Comment: @MaxW that doesn't explain the term "dry" which is the focus of my question. By opposition I suppose there is also the $e_{aq}^{-}$ ? (adding this to the question)

Example on pp 2 in https://www3.nd.edu/~ndrlrcdc/Compilations/rxn.pdf

Comment: $e_{aq}^-$ is quite a natural thing; that's a [hydrated electron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solvated_electron). Just rip an electron off something and let it go in the water (not that it would survive there for long, but anyway). But _dry electron_ sounds pretty weird to me.

Comment: @Sosi - :-( again - A "dry electron" is a free electron which  still has some of the kinetic energy from the event which created it. When it loses enough kinetic energy so that it becomes solvated then it is $e^{-}_{(aq)} $.

Comment: Yes, I got that; I just wanted to note that it _still_ sounds strange to me.

Comment: @MaxW, would you like to post that as an answer please?

Thanks everyone for the patience to answer such rookie questions!

Answer (score 5):

A "dry" electron is an electron released from the event of an ionization. Depend on source the electron can either be defined as:

> "The $e^-$ is a 'dry electron' that still retains some of the excess
>   kinetic energy acquired from the ionizing event."$\ce{^{[1]}}$

or,

> "The 'dry-electron' (defined as an electron before solvation)
>   ..."$\ce{^{[2]}}$

A dry electron is thus, an electron that is not assiciated with any atoms, molecules or solutions.

**Reference**

$\ce{[1]}$ Thormod Henriksen, David H. Maillie; Radiation and Health; page 157

$\ce{[2]}$ J.D. Simon; Ultrafast Dynamics of Chemical Systems; page 144